# Конструкторы Java

Tags: ооп, java, конструктор

Всем Привет!

Есть базовый конструктор:

```
public abstract class JS {

    public Context context;

    public JS(Context con)
    {
        context=con;
    }

    public JS(){}
}
```

**И его наследник:**

```
public class jsEnter extends JS { ... }
```

**Попытка создать объект:**

```
jsEnter js = new jsEnter(Context.this);
```

**Ошибка: конструктора с такими параметрами не существует...**

Будьте добры, скажите, почему так? В других объектных языках это работает, но не в Java..

Comment: Насколько понимаю, Вы создаете `jsEnter js` из какого-то метода класса `Context`?

Вы бы описание классов `jsEnter` и `Context` привели.

Наверное в классе `jsEnter` нет подходящего конструктора. Уже из него Вам надо будет вызвать `super()` с нужным параметром.

Comment: Суть классов в данном случае не имеет никакого значения. Все, что касается проблемы, приведено. Да, спасибо, я уж думал, что в данном случае можно было бы обойтись и без явного вызова конструктора базового класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам старшие товарищи уже все разъяснили, но позволю пару замечаний:

1. В абстрактных классах обычно не создаются публичные конструкторы, поскольку они бессмысленны - надеюсь понятно почему
2. Я конечно, не [grammar nazi](http://lurkmore.to/Grammar_nazi), но отмечу, что имя класса должно быть с большой буквы - согласно общепринятым нормам изложенным в [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
public abstract class JS {    
   public Context context;    
   protected JS(Context con) {        
      context=con;    
   }

   protected JS() {
   }
}

public class JSEnter extends JS {
   public JSEnter(Context context) {
     super(context);
   }

   public JSEnter() {
     super();
   }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за замечания. От установленных норм, и правда, никогда не стоит отходить куда-либо в сторону.

Answer (score 5):

- У языкового решения с неявным наследованием конструкторов больше проблем, чем пользы.

> - Представьте себе, например, что у каждого из ваших объектов есть базовый класс `Object,` который содержит конструктор без параметров `Object().`
> - Этот конструктор имеет вполне определенный смысл для `Object,` но может не иметь смысла для **всех его потенциальных наследников.** Например, вы пишете класс `DatabaseLock,` который является наследником `Object,` но при этом не имеет смысла, будучи сконструированным в отрыве от экземпляра класса `Database.`
> - Если бы конструкторы наследовались, ваш `DatabaseLock : public Object` получил бы такой конструктор и позволил бы вашим пользователям сконструировать отвязанный от контекста `lock,` который не имел бы никакого смысла, но был бы возможен вследствие наследования конструкторов.

- В `Java` конструкторы не наследуются ([`Java Language Specification, section 8.8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#8.8)):

> Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding.

- `C++11` решает проблему с написанием `boilerplate` кода для конструкторов в классах-наследниках с помощью [`constructor inheritance.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979194/what-is-constructor-inheritance)

> Заметьте, что это решение фундаментально отличается от того, что пишете вы, поскольку в этом случае в классах наследниках **явно** указывается, что конструкторы наследуются.

- Ваше утверджение про то, что *"в других объектных языках это работает",* естественно, неверно.

Comment: Да уж, хреново. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Конструкторы в Java не наследуются. Вам нужно явным образом определить конструктор в классе-наследнике. Если вы хотите, чтобы он делал то же, что и конструктор предка, то нужно явно вызвать конструктор предка при помощи ключевого слова `super`. Обратите внимание, что вызов конструктора класса-предка должен быть первой строкой конструктора класса-наследника. Исключение только для ситуации, когда должен быть вызван конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров) класса-предка.

P.S. Что за дурацкая фраза "В других объектных языках это работает"? По-вашему, все объектно-ориентированные языки ддолжны иметь одинаковый синтаксис? Какой тогда вообще смысл  в существовании нескольких языков?